# Android-x86 6.0 Marshmallow in VirtualBox doesn't start

Tags: virtualbox, android, android-x86

I succesfully installed [android-x86-6.0_20160129.iso](https://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/Testing/) in VirtualBox but the VM doesn't start.

This is my GRUB:

[image]

If I start the VM with the first option I get error `Failed to find cpu0 device node`. I found out that it's just a [non-blocking warning](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254210) and it's unrelated with the real blocking-issue being that "uvesa (v86d) is broken" (the issue was related to Android 4.4: is it still valid on 6.0?)

[image]

If I choose the Debug mode, I see some messages and a hint to type `exit` to boot, but still no success

[image]

[image]

Some background:

- The VM was created from the Ubuntu 32-bit (x86) VirtualBox template
- The VM has 1 core + 3096 MB RAM
- Video memory: 32 MB
- PAE/NX enabled
- Hardware virtualization: both VTx and nested pagination enabled
- Graphics acceleration: disabled (both 2D and 3D)
- Storage: 64 GB attached to IDE virtual controller (was SATA before: makes no difference)

I've already tried all the "standard" VirtualBox procedure (PAE yes/no; SATA/IDE; no soundcard; no USB; graphics accel. yes/no).

I also tried run the Live CD in VESA mode: like this it starts, but I'd still prefer to run it from the HDD.

Comment: Have you tried using two cpu cores?

Comment: @Robert  : I have now: no difference

Comment: tried this on DebianLinux-VirtualBox and I got to the colorful 'circles' screen but no further - it just sits there endlessly (1GB RAM+1x1stgen CPU core)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

1. At the Grub screen, press `e`.
2. Press `e` again. Add `vga=788` (need a leading space).
3. Press `b` to boot.

---

To make this permanent, at the Grub screen, select the second choice.
Then follow these steps.

1. `cd /mnt/grub`
2. `vi menu.lst`
3. On the 7th line which starts with `kernel`, press `a` and then type `vga=788` (need a leading space).
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `:wq` to save the file and quit.
5. Press the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, select Machine > Reset and then click "Reset".

The error will still appear, but now it will continue on.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the Grub boot screen press 'e'
2. Edit the boot command and add:

   ```
   'acpi=off'
   ```
3. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to continue booting into Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps for your case but for me it helped, that I uninstalled the current Version of VirtualBox, installed the older 5.2.0, then I could install Android and it didn't hung at first startup this time. After it was installed and booted for the first time I could update my VirtualBox (again) to the newest Version and Android booted fine like under 5.2.0. It was only the first startup - with configuration - as it seems where you need the older VirtualBox-Version.

Answer (score 0):

Using 32bit version worked for me. Also try an older Android version.