# Stuck At [A N D R O I D root@x86:/ #] in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, android, android-x86

I'm just having problem installing Androidx86 Marshmallow Version in Virtualbox, yes installation was success but whenever I am booting with it, I always receive this message..

```
input_data: 0x0151c101 <br/>
input_len: 0x004b411e <br/>
output: 0x01000000 <br/>
output_len: 0x009bef7c <br/>
run_size: 0x00a76000 <br/>

Decompressing Linux... Parsing Elf... No Relocation Needed... done.<br>
Booting the kernel.<br>
[    0.803765] Failed to find cpu0 device node<br>
Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sda1<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>




                         A N D R O I D root@x86:/ #
```

Comment: Related to the still unanswered question [Android-x86 6.0 Marshmallow in VirtualBox doesn't start](http://superuser.com/questions/1052799/android-x86-6-0-marshmallow-in-virtualbox-doesnt-start). Did you read [this page](http://www.tactig.com/install-android-6-0-marshmallow-virtualbox-pc/) or a similar one? Can you add the procedure you followed?

Comment: Yeah I already read on that, but no solution

Comment: @Hastur It works without using virtualbox but the problem is grub boot loader removes windows in the list. I'm so unfortunate

Comment: Did you tried with a pre-installed virtual HD? For example from [here](http://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/)? when I recently installed with another OS version I remain in a similar situation, with the working prompt, but for my purposes was enough a pre-installed version. Give it a look to the [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) site too.